# Using related_name to call objects attributes in django templates

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-templates

I have 3 models. User, Post and Proof. Posts are added by a User to the website. When other users do what the post says. They upload 2 images to say they did the task. The template will show the 2 images they uploaded. I know I am making some mistake in the template calling the images. Does anyone know the correct way to use related_name to call for the images. FYI I am new to python and Django I am sorry if this question is too trivial or has wrong logic

Proof/models.py

```
User = get_user_model()

class Proof(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='proofmade')
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='postproofmade')
    made_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    image_of_task= models.ImageField()
    proof_you_made_it = models.ImageField()
    suggestions = models.TextField(max_length=1000)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.post.title
```

Templates

```
{% for user in post.made.all  %}
<div class="container">
   <img src="{{ user.proofmade.image_of_task.url }}" height="150px"/>
   <img src="{{ user.proofmade.proof_you_made_it.url }}" height="150px"/>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Post/views.py

```
class PostDetail(SelectRelatedMixin, DetailView):
    model = Post
    select_related = ('user', 'group')

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        return queryset.filter(user__username__iexact=self.kwargs.get('username'))
```

Comment: There's not nearly enough information here. What is `post`? Where is `made` defined as a related name? Please show the view at least.

Comment: @DanielRoseman The views just have the CreateView and DeleteView adding them now

Comment: But which view is responsible for rendering that template? Again, what is `post`?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I am sorry I have added the views that are responsible for the template

Comment: That is a redirect, and is not responsible for displaying any template at all.

Comment: @DanielRoseman thank you so much for being so patient with me. I have added the detailView. I was not adding too many details as it makes the question look too complicated. The name of the template is post_detail.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A ForeignKey is a one-to-many relationship; the related_name therefore gives access to a queryset corresponding to many items. You need to iterate over that queryset to get the individual items, in this case the Proof instances - just as you do with the users for each post. So, something like:

```
{% for user in post.made.all  %}
   {% for proof in user.proofmade.all %}
    <div class="container">
       <img src="{{ proof.image_of_task.url }}" height="150px"/>
       <img src="{{ proof.proof_you_made_it.url }}" height="150px"/>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Hi Daniel Roseman I know I am asking a doubt on this after almost a month. but I just realized there may be a small problem with this code. If the user has 2 proofs on 2 entirely different posts. The forloop runs 2 times on both of them. Is it possible to modify the code such that. The forloop runs only once. That is: if the user has proof in a particular post it will show the proof. if not it will not show